# Powershell function receiving multiple parameters from pipeline

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, pipeline

I'm writing a function as follows:

```
Function Display-ItemLocation {
   Param(
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory   = $True,
         Valuefrompipeline = $True ) ]
         [ String ]$stringItem,
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory   = $False,
         Valuefrompipeline = $True ) ]
         [ String ]$stringLocation = 'unknown' 
   )
     Echo "The location of item $stringItem is $stringLocation."
}

Display-ItemLocation 'Illudium Q-36 Explosive Space Modulator' 'Mars'
Display-ItemLocation 'Plumbus'
```

It works fine as written.

```
The location of item Illudium Q-36 Explosive Space Modulator is Mars.
The location of item Plumbus is unknown.
```

I'd like to be able to pre-load an array with multiple data pairs and send it via pipeline into the function.

```
$Data = @(
           @('Bucket','Aisle 1'),
           @('Spinach Pie','Freezer 4')
         )
$Data | Display-ItemLocation
```

I can't find the magic syntax to get this to work.  Can the function accept a pair of values at the same time from the pipeline?

Comment: Not really, you can only have one input stream that sort of "drives" the pipeline and binds to a single parameter. If you're exclusively writing this for PowerShell 5.0 and up, you could take advantage of custom class definitions and use that as a pipeline-enabled input type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Define your pipeline-binding parameters as binding by *property name* - `ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName` - and then pipe (custom) *objects* that have such properties**:

```
Function Display-ItemLocation {
   Param(
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory,
         ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName ) ]
         [ String ]$stringItem,
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory = $False,
         ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName ) ]
         [ String ]$stringLocation = 'unknown' 
   )
   
   process { # !! You need a `process` block to process *all* input objects.
     Echo "The location of item $stringItem is $stringLocation."
   }

}
```

<sup>As an aside: `Display` is not an [approved verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) in PowerShell.</sup>

Now you can pipe to the function as follows; note that the property names must match the parameter names:

```
$Data = [pscustomobject] @{ stringItem = 'Bucket'; stringLocation = 'Aisle 1' },
        [pscustomobject] @{ stringItem = 'Spinach Pie'; stringLocation = 'Freezer 4' }

$Data | Display-ItemLocation
```

The above yields:

```
The location of item Bucket is Aisle 1.
The location of item Spinach Pie is Freezer 4.
```

---

- The above **uses `[pscustomobject]` instances**, which are easy to construct ad hoc.

  - Note that ***hash tables*** (e.g., just `@{ stringItem = 'Bucket'; stringLocation = 'Aisle 1' }`) **do *not* work** - although changing that is being discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13104).
- In PSv5+ you could **alternatively define a custom `class`**:

```
# Define the class.
class Product {
  [string] $stringItem
  [string] $stringLocation
  Product([object[]] $itemAndLocation) { 
    $this.stringItem = $itemAndLocation[0]
    $this.stringLocation = $itemAndLocation[1]
  }
}

# Same output as above.
[Product[]] (
  ('Bucket', 'Aisle 1'), 
  ('Spinach Pie', 'Freezer 4')
) | Display-ItemLocation
```

Comment: Thank you... You answer led me to the solution I wanted (which I'll post momentarily).  I thought the `[PSCustomObject]` as you listed it was too verbose, so I reworked the code to use the array as I envisioned it for brevity.

Comment: Just curious, what would you use for a verb?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Tony. As for reducing the verbosity - please see my update. As for what verb to use: if you're _converting to a different data format_, use `ConvertTo`. If you're creating _for-display-only_ representations, use `Format`, but then you should use `Write-Host` or `Out-Host` to emit the for-display representations  rather than outputting to the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mklement0 for leading me to this solution.  I came up with two options to resolve my dilemma using an array.

**Option 1**: Use `.ForEach` to pass the parameters in the usual way.

```
$Data = @(
           @('Bucket','Aisle 1'),
           @('Spinach Pie','Freezer 4')
         )

$Data.ForEach({Format-ItemLocation "$($_[0])" "$($_[1])"})
```

**Option 2**: Using the pipeline (which is what I was after), I modified the function as mklement0 suggested to enable the `ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName` and to include a `Process { }` block.

```
Function Format-ItemLocation {
   Param (
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory   = $True,
         ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $True ) ]
         [ String ]$stringItem,
      [ Parameter ( 
         Mandatory   = $False,
         ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $True ) ]
         [ String ]$stringLocation = 'unknown' 
   )
   Process {
       "The location of item $stringItem is $stringLocation."
   }
}
```

I pass the array via pipeline to a middle step to assign the parameter names to a `[PSCustomObject]`.  This greatly reduces the amount of text that would bulk up the code, and it's the reason I was searching for a more elegant solution.

```
$Data = @(
           @('Bucket','Aisle 1'),
           @('Spinach Pie','Freezer 4')
         )

$Data | 
   ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{stringItem=$_[0];stringLocation=$_[1]} } |
   Format-ItemLocation
```

<sup>I changed the function name to `Format-*` as recommended.</sup>